# Java HTTP Servlet Duplicate Submission

Tags: java, spring, web-services, servlets

My problem is that I submit a file for upload.  About 3 minutes into the server processing the file (before the response is written to the output stream) something is resubmitting the file.  I do not know what process is initiating the resubmission.  I suspect it is something from the client side.

My setup on the server is a class which extends HttpServlet mapped in the web.xml with the doPost doing the work.

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.myorg.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

On the client there is a simple form with a submit button.

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='/MyJavaApplication/ws/rest'>
  <input name='uploadFile' type='file' size='45'/>
  <input name='submit' type='submit' value='Upload Document'/>
</form>
```

When I look at the stack trace in both the initial and duplicate submission, I see exactly the same entry point:

```
QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run line 582
```

There are a number of servlet filters, for example we use spring security and also have some custom filters which log the request before passing it on.

I am really stumped by this problem, so any help would be appreciated.

**NOTE This was a Jetty 6.1.26 issue - changing to version 8 resolved the problem**

Comment: Can you confirm whether it is definitely the client that is submitting the duplicate request? If you press F12 in your browser you can bring up the developer tools console and view the networking tab. Here you should be able to see the requests go out.

Comment: Looking at the network traffic in the developer tools shows that there is only one request.  I put a breakpoint in the java code to trap the second request, and let the first request run until completion.  The strange thing is, the output from the first request is not written back to the client - but the output from the second request is.  I am running in Elcipse with Jetty, so perhaps this is a servlet container issue.  I'll try with a different version of Jetty.

Comment: Annoyingly it was Jetty 6.1.26 when I changed to version 8.x it was resolved.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the upload which is taking a long time, or the server processing the file after upload?

If it is the server processing, here is what I suggest:

Process the uploaded file in a different thread. This will mean that the servlet is able to send the response while the processing is still in progress. To prevent re-submissions, the servlet can respond with a Redirect:

```
response.sendRedirect("results-page-url");  //change the url to suit your app
```

Any re-submissions will then go straight to the redirected URL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It is the server processing that takes the time.  The problem is the response must contain the outcome of the submission, which means it can not be written until after the submission has been processed.  I can not change this, as it must conform to a ISO specification which the service implements.